# Plotting a System of Two Differential Eqns Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, modeling, differential-equations

I am having some trouble with a model I want to analyze. I am trying to plot two differential equations however I am very new to doing this and am not getting it to work. Any help is appreciated

```
#Polyaneuploid cell development during cancer
#two eqns
#Fixed Points:
#13.37526 
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def modelC(C,t):
  
  λc = 0.0601 
  K = 2000 
  α = 1 * (10**-4) 
  ν = 1 * (10**-6) 
  λp = 0.1 
  γ = 2

def modelP(P,t):
  
  λc = 0.0601 
  K = 2000 
  α = 1 * (10**-4) 
  ν = 1 * (10**-6) 
  λp = 0.1 
  γ = 2
  

#returning odes
  dPdt = ((λp))*P(1-(C+(γ*P))/K)+ (α*C) 
  dCdt = ((λc)*C)(1-(C+(γ*P))/K)-(α*C) + (ν*P) 
  return dPdt, dCdt

#initial conditions

C0= 256 
P0 = 0 

#time points
t = np.linspace(0,30)

#solve odes
P = odeint(modelP,t,P0, args = (C0,))
C = odeint(modelC,t,C0, args= (P0,))

#P = odeint(modelP, P0 , t)
#P = P[:, 2]

#C = odeint(modelC, C0 , t)
#C = C[:, 2]


#plot results
plt.plot(t,np.log10(C0))
plt.plot(t,np.log10(P0))
plt.xlabel('time in days')
plt.ylabel('x(t)')
plt.show()
```

This is just what I have so far, and currently I am getting this error: ValueError: diff requires input that is at least one dimensional
Any tips on how to get the graphs to show?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your initial conditions in a list like so:

```
initial_conditions = [C0, P0]
P = odeint(modelP,t,initial_conditions)
```

you still have some error in your P function where try to access C which is not defined in the local scope of your function neither passed as an argument.

**UPDATED**

```
def modelP(P,t,C):
  
  λc = 0.0601 
  K = 2000 
  α = 1 * (10**-4) 
  ν = 1 * (10**-6) 
  λp = 0.1 
  γ = 2
  

#returning odes
  dPdt = ((λp))*P(1-(C+(γ*P))/K)+ (α*C) 
  dCdt = ((λc)*C)(1-(C+(γ*P))/K)-(α*C) + (ν*P) 
  return dPdt, dCdt

#initial conditions

C0= 256 
P0 = 0 
Pconds = [P0]
#time points
t = np.linspace(0,30)

#solve odes
P = odeint(modelP,t, Pconds, args=(C0,))
```

Comment: Thanks. I am now getting the error you talked about where C is not defined, did I not define C when I listed it in modelC?

Comment: I tried to define it by replacing C in modelC(C,t) with modelC(x,t) and saying C= x and P = x but now the error I am getting is a type error where it states that numpy.ndarray is not callable

Comment: Could you provide your code for that?

Comment: Why did you defined modelC thou, it has no return and it is just duplicating the code in your modelP

Comment: def modelC(x,t):
C = x
P = x         this is what I changed. That makes more sense, so if I want to plot both differentials, I wouldn't need to define two models, I could just use one?

Comment: Ok I think I get what you are trying to achieve, try this out. Basically we added C as a parameter to the function and passed it as an argument and now Pconds is just P0 in a list (I'm going to edit answer to show new code)

Comment: This is also wrong. You return 2 values, thus the state has to be 2-dimensional. `def model(x,t): C,P = x; ...` would realize that.

Answer (score 0):

The solver deals with flat arrays with no inherent meaning in the components. You need to add that meaning, unpack the input vector into the state object, at the start of the model function, and remove that meaning, reduce the state to a flat array or list, at the end of the model function.

Here this is simple, the state consists of 2 scalars. Thus a structure for the model function is

```
def model(X,t):
    P, C = X
    ....
    return dPdt, dCdt
```

Then integrate as

```
X = odeint(model,(P0,C0),t)
P,C = X.T

plt.plot(t,P)
```